# Laravel OAuth2 Server

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I am new with **Oauth Server**.

I get this error:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 737:
>
> Class \App\PasswordVerifier does not exist

Grant type is:

```
'grant_types' => [
        'password' => [
            'class' => '\League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant',
            'callback' => '\App\PasswordVerifier@verify',
            'access_token_ttl' => 3600
        ]
    ],
```

I also create controller **PasswordVerifier**.

My question is where i can create **PasswordVerifier** class?

Comment: your error says that class \App\PasswordVerifier not exists

Comment: @user1362776, Yes. So where i can create PasswordVerifier  Class?

Comment: i think you need to follow namespace path. if laravel 5 - in app directory where your models situated. namespace App, classname PasswordVerifier

Comment: @RomaRush: Its working now.